# Mapped network drive cannot be deleted, but shows up in Explorer; connects to wrong server

Tags: vpn, routing, windows-server-2012, shared-folders

This is the most bizarre problem I've ever encountered.

Summary:  A mapped network drive persists in Windows Explorer and cannot be deleted/disconnected (claims it does not exist; net use shows nothing; net use drive: /delete fails on it).  Strangely, the mapped drive connects after a while, despite the VPN connection it requires is not connected.  Even stranger, it connects to the wrong server altogether, which should be impossible, considering the mapped drive should have no way of even identifying it without the VPN connection active.

Details...

I had two mapped network drives.

Each of the two established a connection through a VPN to completely different servers.  One was mapped to (Z:) 192.168.1.2, and the other to (W:) 192.168.2.1, as each VPN server established a different range for their VPN clients (192.168.1.* vs 192.168.2.*).  Note that those are not local machines, but remote servers made to appear as local machines when the VPN is active, using Windows Server 2012 Routing and Remote Access feature.  Server "IT" established itself as 192.168.1.2, and server "WW" as 192.168.2.1, and they are completely different servers with different/dissimilar WAN addresses, although they're in the same virtual hosting center.

Both mapped drives used to function as expected when both VPNs were active.

When I restarted my client (Windows 7) machine, obviously both VPNs are inactive, but one of the drives (Z:) 192.168.1.2 establishes a connection after a while, despite no active VPN.

Strangely, it appears to be connecting to the wrong server "WW" instead of "IT", and I've confirmed this by creating a file in the mapped drive (WTF.txt) in explorer and confirming that it was successfully created on the server by logging in through remote desktop and navigating to the physical folder.

This makes absolutely not sense to me.  There is no VPN active, so when mapping a drive to a LAN address like 192.168.1.2 that shouldn't exist when the VPN is inactive, how on Earth is that mapped drive not only able to locate the remote server in another part of the state, but also establish a connection to it?  Why does it persist in Windows Explorer despite being deleted/disconnected.

Interestingly, if I activate the VPN and map the drive again with the same letter and same LAN address (192.168.1.2), it establishes a connection to the correct server and shows as active again in Windows Explorer.  It still persists even if I disconnect/delete it after doing this.... it's like some stable wormhole has been embedded in windows explorer linking a mapped drive to the wrong server and keeps reasserting itself when I restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First of all, the drive has to be connected in order to delete it.  That seems to be a general issue with mapped drives in Windows.

Second, the reason the Client was able to connect to Server B, despite the only active VPN from the Client being to Server A, is that Server B also had established a VPN connection to Server A, using the same account as the Client.

The issue was a freak VPN address conflict of sorts, that arose from not only using the same account for two different clients, but the order in which they connected, and the fallback address windows chose conflicted with the server's own loopback adapter address.

Normally, the Client and Server B each have their own user account for dialing in to the VPN of Server A, and they each had different static IP's assign in their user accounts Dial-In tab, so normally the Client and Server B would each get their own static IP without any conflict.

For some reason, instead of using Server B's own account, I had used the client's account to connect, which is basically my main user account... a simple mistake.  I noticed this in RRAS, when I saw two clients were connected under the same username.  I know one was my client machine, but the other had been active for over 900 hours.  That's when I realized it must be Server B connecting to Server A, but it failed to use its own user account.
So that's where it got interesting.  Some time 900+ hours ago, the client must have connected first, and received the proper static IP: 192.168.1.101.  Then Server B must have connected afterwards while the client's VPN was still active, and since the client was already logged in under that same account, it could not be assigned the chosen static IP, so Windows just decided to fall back to the next IP address available in the static routes range, which happened to be 192.168.1.2.  So Server B now has an VPN IP address of 192.168.1.2.  Which would be fine except...

That's a problem, because that's the IP (192.168.1.2) I assigned to Server A's loopback adapter.  That's supposed to be the IP I use to access Server A on the VPN when the client is connected, except now Server B thinks it's also 192.168.1.2.

So there was an undetectable IP address conflict going on, which explains the bizarre behavior.  Namely, that when I first connected to the VPN for Server A, the address 192.168.1.2 was routing to Server B, and if I simply disconnected and reconnected the drive to that same IP, it would find Server A instead.  I'm not sure how windows makes the decision of which computer to route to when an RRAS client and the Microsoft Loopback adapter end up assign to the same IP address.

Honestly, this is a dumb bug in Windows Server, because the RRAS server should have known to not assign an IP address in the given range that was already taken by another adapter (the loopback adapter).  Perhaps it only tracks IPs and tests for conflicts with IPs it assigns itself, and doesn't have any way of knowing whether existing adapters are already using an IP in the allowed range.

The whole thing was a freak combination of events... Server B connected after Server A using the same account instead of its own, since the static IP for that account was already taken, RRAS then stupidly assigned an IP address to it from the allowed range, without first checking for conflicts, and it ended up giving Server B the same IP as Server A's loopback adapter.  Then when the client tried to access that IP, Windows would thing it was Server B at first, but a disconnect/reconnect of the mapped drive to that same IP would then resolve to Server A.  Incredibly strange.

In any case, all I have to do is bump the allowed range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.3, so it never assigns it's own static IP to any clients, which wasn't supposed to happen, given that they all were assigned their own static IPs, except that when they connected with the same account, it had no choice but to fall back to something in the allowed range.